# Opencv c++ thread looping imshow

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to open multiple windows in a c++ program which have to be refreshed constantly. So I wrote this code:

```
        void Seedselector::seedsInit()
        {
            vector<thread> th;
        
            unsigned int k = 0;
            for (vector<vector<Point3i*>>::iterator itr = points.begin(); itr < points.end();itr++)
            {   
                const string name = "Fig. " + to_string(k + 1);
                namedWindow(name,CV_GUI_EXPANDED);
                setMouseCallback(name, onmouse, &slices[k]);
                setMouseCallback(name, onmouse2, &slices[k]); 
                th.push_back(thread(&Seedselector::onThread, this, slices[k], name));
            }
        
            for (vector<thread>::iterator itr = th.begin(); itr < th.end(); itr++)
                (*itr).join();
        
            k = 0;
            for (vector<vector<Point3i*>>::iterator itr1 = points.begin(); itr1 < points.end(); itr1++)
            {
                for (vector<Point3i*>::iterator itr2 = (*itr1).begin(); itr2 < (*itr1).end(); itr2++)
                    (*itr2)->z = *(idslices.begin() + k) - 1;
                k++;
            }
        }
    
    void Seedselector::onThread(Mat *sl, string name)
    {
        do
        {
            imshow(name, *sl);
            waitKey(500);
        } while (!exit);
    }
    
    void Seedselector::onmouse(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param)
    {
        vector<Point3i*> *pt = (vector<Point3i*> *)param;
    
        if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && flag == CV_EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON)
            if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < rows && y < cols )
            {
                pt->push_back(new Point3i(x, y, 0));
    
                cout << "selecting x: " << x << "y: " << y << endl;
            }
    
            if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
            {
                destroyAllWindows();
                exit = true;
            }
        
    }

void Seedselector::onmouse2(int event, int x, int y, int flag, void* param)
{
    Mat* img = static_cast<Mat*> (param);

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && flag == CV_EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON)
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < rows && y < cols)
         {
            circle(*img, Point(x, y), 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 4, 0);
         } 
}
```

with exit being a global variable set to false.

Strangely, it arrives at the imshow, but then the image is not shown and according to the debugger it never executes the waitkey command... any suggestion on the matter?

Ok, since more code was requested I'll go further in the matter. I need to paint on those images using a couple of mouse listeners one of which saves the points "colored" and the other one doing the actual "painting".

So the goal is to "paintbrush" on the images and then saves all the painted points in the vector of vector of points ( yes the nested vector is needed ).

Comment: So you are refreshing a window with the same identical image? Btw, Point3i* is probably something you should avoid. What's points? Slices? Etc... More code needed! (something we can copy&paste&run)

Comment: Also, can you better explain better your main goal? It seems that your approach is wrong

Comment: Before going any deeper, be sure that you can actually have 2 mouse listener in opencv. I don't think so

Comment: i was thinking about that... but i don't see why not

Comment: Because opencv is not really that fancy when it comes to gui. I'm not entirely sure, however. You should check that before going further

Comment: can you try to call cv::namedWindow just before the imshow? implicit window creation by imshow call often fails (and then freezes) on threads.

Comment: OpenCV's gui is not really made for this kind of stuff. I would not recommend using it for anything more than debugging purposes.

Comment: thank you guys. I'll use roy or qt then.